# Bottom Navigation Bar Sticks to Top of Keyboard

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

It seems that a recent update of Flutter changed the behavior of the BottomNavigationBar. Formerly, when the keyboard appeared, the keyboard would cover the BottomNavigationBar. Now, however, the BottomNavigationBar sticks to the top of the keyboard when it appears and is always visible.

How do I set the BottomNavigationBar to remain underneath the keyboard when the keyboard appears?

```
  bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      fixedColor: Colors.blue,
      onTap: _navigationTapped,
      currentIndex: _pageIndex,
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.apps), title: new Text("Manage")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.multiline_chart), title: new Text("A")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.check_box), title: new Text("B")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.person_add), title: new Text("C")),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.border_color), title: new Text("D")),
      ]
  ),
```

Comment: I'm running Flutter with the master channel and the behavior is still the same. The bottomnavbar remains below the keyboard. Can you post a part of your code, maybe you're using an argument that makes the bottomnavbar go up with the keyboard.

Answer (score 14):

Please make sure the widget tree including the parent only contain `one` scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
      body: const TextField(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        fixedColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: (int value) {
          return value;
        },
        currentIndex: 0,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.apps), title: new Text("Manage")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.multiline_chart), title: new Text("A")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.check_box), title: new Text("B")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.person_add), title: new Text("C")),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.border_color), title: new Text("D")),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

---

This will cause bottom navigation being pushed above keyboard.

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Scaffold(
        ....
```

Comment: it doesn't make any sense, i am using two scaffold one inside other, and by setting resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, inside upper scaffold i have fixed this problem.

Comment: I was looking for the opposite, I needed the bottom navigation bar to stick above the keyboard. Thanks to your explanation I have managed to set it. Thank you.

Comment: This answer should be accepted!! It solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

Do you have `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in your Scaffold? That causes the bottomBar to go up when the keyboard appears

Answer (score 2):

if your flutter version is before **1.1.9**

use

```
return Scaffold(
         resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
         ...
```

else

```
return Scaffold(
         resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
         ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bottomsheet` instead of `bottomNavBar`
and then make `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `true`. This would make it appear above the keyboard when it shows.

Answer (score -1):

Be notice if you have a scaffold widget on the previous page from bottombar page