How to make the bottomBar appear above the keyboard when focus comes to textField in jetpack compose?
I want the bottomBar to appear above my keyboard whenever the focus goes to the textfield.
What i want is this:

I tried manipulating the windowInsets but got nowhere and i believe the method won't fix my issue as well as it's meant for the the content inside the scaffold rather than the bottom bar itself.
Is this achievable or not? if yes, then how?
Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            AddPostBottomRow(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .imeNestedScroll()
                    .imePadding()
            )
        },
        contentWindowInsets = ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets
    ) {
        val paddingValues = it.calculateBottomPadding()

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White)

        ) {

            CommentScreenTopBar(
                onCloseClick = { navController.popBackStack() },
                onReplyClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                    .imeNestedScroll()
                    .imePadding()
            ) {
                TweetPartForComment(
                    tweet = tweet,
                    navController = navController,
                    tweetEvent = tweetEvent,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )


                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {

                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Replying to ",
                            fontFamily = roboto,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Thin,
                            color = Color.DarkGray,
                            fontSize = 14.sp
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = "@${tweet.username}",
                            fontFamily = roboto,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Thin,
                            color = colorResource(id = R.color.toggle_button_thumb),
                            fontSize = 14.sp
                        )
                    }
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {


                        AsyncImage(
                            model = getModel(tweet.avatar, context),
                            contentDescription = "user dp",
                            placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.placeholder_image),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(34.dp)
                                .clip(CircleShape),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                        )

                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(12.dp))

                        VerticalDivider(
                            Modifier
                                .width(1.dp)
                                .height(24.dp)
                        )

                        OutlinedTextField(
                            value = "",
                            onValueChange = {
                            },
                            placeholder = {
                                Text(
                                    text = "Post your reply",
                                    fontFamily = roboto,
                                    color = Color.Gray,
                                    fontSize = 14.sp
                                )
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth(1f)
                                .wrapContentHeight(),
                            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Transparent,
                                focusedBorderColor = Color.Transparent
                            ),
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {}),
                            textStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                fontFamily = roboto,
                                lineHeight = 1.2.em
                            )
                        )

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/17728171
would you tried , changing android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or adjustresize ?

use BottomSheet instead of BottomNavBar also you can check in detail here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77406527/25203130
already post the solution .
